# How to compare datetime columns just by time part

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write SQL query that will give me all the rows in which the date of datetime value `Creation_date` is the same as the date of the datetime value `Status_date`. Also, the time part of this datetime values must be in where clause of this query - the exact time part of value `Status_date` needs to be between time part of the value `Creation_date` and 4am, also time part of `Creation_date` needs to be from midnight till 2 AM.

I think I know the first part

```
select *
from a_orders
where trunc(Creation_date)=trunc(Status_date) and ??
```

The table:

```
      Creation_date         Status_date  
1.2019-08-26 00:02:10   2019-08-26 08:35:02
2.2019-08-26 00:02:20   2019-08-26 09:15:18
3.**2019-08-26 00:02:41 2019-08-26 00:20:08**
4.**2019-08-26 00:02:48 2019-08-26 00:20:08**
5.2019-07-29 00:05:28   2019-07-30 00:40:29
```

From the table above, I only need rows 3. and 4. to be in my result.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It is Oracle. Sorry forgot to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit lengthy query but if you are using Oracle try this and see if it works

```
where trunc(Creation_date)=trunc(Status_date) 
and Creation_date between to_date(to_char(d.Creation_date,'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' 00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') and to_date(to_char(d.Creation_date,'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' 02:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')
and Status_date between d.Creation_date and to_date(to_char(d.Creation_date,'MM/DD/YYYY') || ' 04:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use the `TRUNC` function, I suppose we're talking about Oracle and that the columns are of type `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`.

> Creation_date needs to be from midnight till 2 AM:

```
Creation_date - TRUNC(Creation_date) <= 2/24
```

> Status_date needs to be between time part of the value Creation_date
>   and 4AM:

```
Status_date BETWEEN Creation_date AND (TRUNC(Status_date) + 4/24)
```

The latter only because you checked before that both dates have the same date part.

Comment: got this error with this two conditions 
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"